# How to couple manually created type with imported npm package in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm writing an electron-react-typescript app with sqlite.
Currently I'm trying to import `sqlite` from `better-sqlite3-with-prebuilds`:

```ts
const sqlite: any = require('better-sqlite3-with-prebuilds');
const db: any = new sqlite('../../../mytest.db');
exports.db = db;
```

Now, I'd prefer not to sacrifice the benefits of TypeScript (type declarations), so I'm wondering how can I declare a module that imports the required components such that I'd end up with something like this:

```ts
import { sqlite } from "sqlite";

const db: sqlite = new sqlite('../../../mytest.db');
exports.db = db;
```

In a `react-app-env.d.ts` I have defined:

```ts
/// <reference types="react-scripts" />

// need to import better-sqlite3-with-prebuilds here

declare module 'sqlite' {
    export class sqlite {
        constructor(path: string);
    }
}
```

Now again, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to connect my module with the imported package.

Comment: Is the question about patching types for a module with no types/incorrect types?

Comment: @youdateme I'm not 100% sure what you're asking but basically I'd just like to have a type instead of *any* in regards of the imported element from "better-sqlite..."

Comment: Ok, I don't understand the question because the second snippet has (seemingly) nothing to do with importing `better-sqlite3-with-prebuilds`. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @youdateme I'm trying to use my self created type/module which is supposed to import `better-sqlite3-with-prebuilds` - I'm not too familiar with self declared types in TypeScript so this was just my attempt. At the end of the day, I just want to be able to write: `const db: **sqlite** = new sqlite('./path')` instead of `const db: **any** = new sqlite('./path')`